# My Ajax call to Code behind Webmethod with MapPageRoute is not working. (Not MVC)

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have a question regarding the usage of ajax post call while using the MapPageRoute code in global.asax .

I'll show you some example that I have used.

In the Global.asax File Code looks like this.

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{            

    RouteTable.Routes.MapPageRoute("ICPDR", "InitialClaimReport", "~/Accounts/PC/Initial_Claim_Report.aspx");

}
```

And in the Js File Look like this.

```
 $.ajax({
    "dataType": 'json',
    "contentType": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    "type": "POST",
    "url": "InitialClaimReport/populate_User/",        
    "data": {},
    "success":
        function (json) {

            $('#ddl_User').find('option').remove();
            $("#ddl_User").append('<option value="0"></option>');
            $.each(JSON.parse(json.d).list, function (key, val) {

                $("#ddl_User").append('<option value="' + val.ID + '">' + val.User+ '</option>');


            });

        },
    "error": function (xhr, status, p3, p4) {
        var err = "Error " + " " + status + " " + p3 + " " + p4;
        if (xhr.responseText && xhr.responseText[0] == "{")
            err = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText).message;
        alert(err);
    }
});
```

And in the Code behind (Initial_Claim_Report.aspx)

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]       
public static string populate_User()
{

        try
        {
            BLL_Users objusr_BLL = new BLL_Users();                
            return objpractice_BLL.Fetch_UserList();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            throw;
        }



 }
```

I have used the above code but My Ajax call is not woking.

Can you please help me to the use of the ajax call while using the routing in asp.net (Not MVC).

When i check in the Chrome console, i got the below error...
POST http://localhost:7777/InitialClaimPendingDetailReport/populate_practice 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Please show the error you're getting - "call is not working" doesn't help very much. What happens? Your question, as it currently is will probably not receive a good answer, and may be closed. Please [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to create a minimal, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for better results using this site. Good luck!

Comment: When i check in the Chrome console. i got this below error..                                POST http://localhost:7777/InitialClaimPendingDetailReport/populate_practice 404 (Not Found)